# Generate dokuwiki code from knitr::spin

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, dokuwiki

I have a script in R that I have marked up and that I convert to HTML using knitr::spin(). I would like to include the output from this script into a dokuwiki wiki, but unfortunately the server doesn't allow me to include the native HTML diretly. The question therefore is how can I "spin to Dokuwiki", rather than Markdown? Is there any quick and easily way to convert markdown to Dokuwiki? And how can images be incorporated into this workflow?

Mark

Comment: You need to redefine the output hooks: http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks#output_hooks The best place to learn how to do it is probably the source code: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/tree/master/R (e.g. hooks-md.R, or hooks-html.R, ...) I do not have time or interest in the work, but I guess I will welcome pull requests on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with R and the library in question. But from your question it sounds that you can output markdown. A simple solution would be to use one of the available markdown plugins for DokuWiki to embed your content:

- https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:markdown
- https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:markdownextra
- https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:markdowku